# Remove the space between option and optgroup

Tags: html, css

I have a select drop down in which there are some options and optgroup. I dont want to use the **label** of optgroup. If i set it to empty or not mention as an attribute of optgroup, i just see a space between optgroup and option element. Is there any way to remove it? Here is a jsfiddle for it.

```html
<select>
    <option>Category 1</option>
    <optgroup>
        <option>a</option>
        <option>b</option>
    </optgroup>
    <option>Category 2</option>
     <optgroup>
        <option>c</option>
        <option>d</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

I want to remove the space between 'Category 1' and 'a', 'Category 2' and 'c'.

**Note: I use the random names for drop-down list, they are different in my project, user can select the category as well. If we make category as label then we cant select it further. So the solution should be in changing css or something like this**

Comment: Optgroups should have labels though - in this case, `<optgroup label="Category 1">`... why are you putting category names as separate options?

Comment: Its my project requirement, i just use the random names. user can select category as well and if we make category as a label of optgroup then it cant select category. Try to answer the solution instead of suggesting other things. Thanks

Comment: @AbdullahDanyal i have given some links to select plugins which can fulfill your requirements and have more functionalities like searching. but in default select control you cannot achieve what you want to do in your way. so use plugins instead of using default select control

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are setting group heading in `<option>` tag. so you have to change your code like below :

```
<select>
   <optgroup label="Category 1">
       <option>a</option>
       <option>b</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="Category 2">
       <option>c</option>
       <option>d</option>
   </optgroup>
</select>
```

And if you want to style this according to you, you should use some select plugins based on jquery

Chosen : [Chosen plugin](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Bootstrap Select : [Bootstrap Select Plugin](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to be able to select a category as well, I would advise the following:

```html
<select>
  <option>-- please select --
  <optgroup label="Category 1">
    <option>All
    <option>a
    <option>b
  <optgroup label="Category 2">
    <option>All
    <option>c
    <option>d
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your stylesheet , Here we are forcefully updating the SumoSelect CSS , If you have no use of labels . This is apt .

```
.SumoSelect > .optWrapper > .options li.group > label{padding: 0px 0px !important;}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also consider a dumb solution like this. It's upsides are - it's simple and it works. The downsides are: some people may call it a bad practice and it doesn't involve optgroups if you absolutely need them for some reason.

```html
<select>
    <option>Category 1</option>
    <option>&emsp;a</option>
    <option>&emsp;b</option>
    <option>Category 2</option>
    <option>&emsp;a</option>
    <option>&emsp;b</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i think this is not the desired solution. this is not a good practice to use &nbsp; like this.

Comment: `&emsp;` may be better to create a "fake" indent.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol wow, you're right, didn't know about the existence of `&emsp;`